# Is forced unwrap always required in swift?

Tags: swift

In the next rows of code I can print the `vint` value without using `!` but vint is an optional value (since the `toInt` function returns an optional value).

```
let vstr = "123"
let vint = str.toInt()

if vint{
    println(vint) // It works... why?
}
```

Shouldn't it be ?

```
println(vint!)
```

Comment: Likely, the behaviour of `println` when it's passed an optional `x` is something along the lines of `if x println(x!); else println("nil");`.

Comment: @PaulManta so it is a sort of automatic behaviour of the println func

Comment: No, the functionality is implemented on the Optional enum

Answer (score 2):

Swift's standard library defines this extension:

```
extension T? : Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}
```

That implements the Printable protocol for all optional values. We cannot see the implementation, but based on its behavior, it seems to print "nil" if the optional is `nil`, otherwise it prints the contained instance.

Comment: The documentation is horrible. Right below the Optional binding section that you linked in the other question, it says:

Comment: `let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
println(possibleString!) // requires an exclamation mark to access its value
// prints "An optional string."
 
let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
println(assumedString)  // no exclamation mark is needed to access its value
// prints "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."`

Comment: @manojlds I think "horrible" is a bit strong ;), but remember this is beta software that was released only a couple weeks ago. The language and the documentation will continue to shift and change. I will submit a bug to apple about that section being misleading